# datepicker used in textbox inside script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

when I use date picker in text box outside script it works fine, iwhich looks like this.

```
<input type="text" id="entry_date" name="entry_date[]"  class="form-control datepicker" data-date-format="<?= config_item('date_picker_format'); ?>"  value=""/>
```

But when I use same date picker function inside script it's not working and I don't know whether it will work like this what the way I gave.Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(function () {    
        $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
    });

var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
var fieldHTML = '<div  class="form-group"><input  class="form-control date_pick datepicker col-lg-2" id="datepicker1" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" type="text" name="entry_date[]" value=""/></div>'; //New input field html 


var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
$(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
    if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
        x++; //Increment field counter
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
    }
});

});
</script>
```

Can You please explain to me howI should call this date picker?

Thank You

Comment: 1. Don't use duplicate ID's and 2. Manually bind the datapicker when an element is added.

Comment: is it inside the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<button class="add_button">Add</button>
 <div class="field_wrapper"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
   var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
   var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
   var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
   var fieldHTML = ''; //New input field html 
   var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1

   $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
       if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
           x++; //Increment field counter
           fieldHTML = '<div  class="form-group"><input  class="form-control date_pick datepicker col-lg-2" id="datepicker' + x + '" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" type="text" name="entry_date[]" value=""/></div>';
           $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
           $("#datepicker" + x).datepicker();
       }
   });
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: i have a doubt if two fields is there means how we can give

Answer (score 0):

Check html appended properly, or put html code separate to jquery, maybe using jquery code appended lately when datepicker function work.

Regards,